# Casting pointer to memory buffer to pointer to VLA

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, c99

in C, I believe the following program is valid: casting a pointer to an allocated memory buffer to an array like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARRSIZE 4

int *getPointer(int num){
    return malloc(sizeof(int) * num);
}

int main(){
    int *pointer = getPointer(ARRSIZE);
    int (*arrPointer)[ARRSIZE] = (int(*)[ARRSIZE])pointer;

    printf("%d\n", sizeof(*arrPointer) / sizeof((*arrPointer)[0]));

    return 0;
}
```

(this outputs **4**).

However, is it safe, in C99, to do this using VLAs?

```
    int arrSize = 4;
    int *pointer = getPointer(arrSize);
    int (*arrPointer)[arrSize] = (int(*)[arrSize])pointer;

    printf("%d\n", sizeof(*arrPointer) / sizeof((*arrPointer)[0]));

    return 0;
```

(also outputs **4**).

Is this legit, according to the C99 standard?

It'd be quite strange if it is legit, since this would mean that VLAs effectively enable *dynamic type creation*, for example, types of the kind `type(*)[variable]`.

Comment: Note: I confirm that the OP's code [compiles on IDEONE](http://ideone.com/AI4yYB) and works as the OP says for array sizes different than 4, meaning that it outputs whatever you set `ARRSIZE` or `arrSize` to.

Comment: It's legit according to the C11 draft spec. I don't have a copy of C99, so I can't confirm it was legit in the previous century.

Comment: @user3386109: I am asking about C99, since in C11 VLAs are *optional*

Comment: OT: Printing as `%d` is inappropriate here, as `sizeof` returns at least `unsigned` if not also `long`.

Comment: @alk: you mean I should use `%zd` or `%zu`? I thought they were considered a discouraged practice.

Comment: Just use what is available on the target platform.

Comment: @alk `sizeof` yields `size_t`. (This may or may not be a typedef for a standard unsigned type).

Comment: @Mints97 `%zu` is correct practice for `size_t`. If not on a C99-compatible platform you will have to cast to a known unsigned type and use the correct modifier for that type. There's no such thing as `%zd`.

Comment: @hyde: thank you, I understand your concern. I'll try to follow your advice in the future. I'm not exactly a seasoned SO user, you see =)

Comment: @MattMcNabb, yes there is `%zd`. It is for the signed type corresponding to `size_t`.

Comment: @Mints97, also consider dropping your allocation function completely. It does nothing a simple `malloc(sizeof(int[n][m]))` couldn't achieve and you would avoid a superflouous cast. Casts are bad.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this is legit, and yes, the *variably-modified type system* is extremely useful.  You can use natural array syntax to access a contiguous 2-D array both of whose dimensions were not known until runtime.

It could be called syntactic sugar as there's nothing you can do with these types that you couldn't do without them, but it makes for clean code (in my opinion).

Comment: Thank you, this is an interesting answer. I never considered using VLAs as 2D arrays.

Comment: @Mints97 in case it didn't occur to you already, you can use the SO-approved [malloc idiom](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1505939) `ptr = malloc(N * sizeof *ptr);` here too, e.g. `int (*ptr)[cols] = malloc(rows * sizeof *ptr);`

Comment: thanks, I know that =) I was just interested in this intricacy of C's type system.

Comment: I use this frequently to take a 1-D array of floats (example [20] floats), and typecast it into either 5x4 matrix, a 4x5 matrix, a 2x10 matrix, etc, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it is valid. The [Final version of the C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (cited on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99#References)) says in paragraph 7.5.2 - Array declarators alinea 5 :
*If the size is an expression that is not an integer constant expression: ...
each time it is evaluated it shall have a value greater than zero. The size of each instance
of a variable length array type does not change during its lifetime*.

It even explicitely says that it can be used in a `sizeof` **provided the size never changes** : *Where a size
expression is part of the operand of a sizeof operator and changing the value of the
size expression would not affect the result of the operator, it is unspecified whether or not
the size expression is evaluated*.

But the standard also says that this is only allowed in a block scope declarator or a function prototype : *An ordinary identifier (as defined in 6.2.3) that has a variably modified type shall have
either block scope and no linkage or function prototype scope. If an identifier is declared
to be an object with static storage duration, it shall not have a variable length array type.*

And an example later explains that it cannot be used for member fields, even in a block scope :

```
...
void fvla(int m, int C[m][m]); // valid: VLA with prototype scope
void fvla(int m, int C[m][m]) // valid: adjusted to auto pointer to VLA
{
    typedef int VLA[m][m]; // valid: block scope typedef VLA
    struct tag {
        int (*y)[n]; // invalid: y not ordinary identifier
        int z[n]; // invalid: z not ordinary identifier
    };
...
```